# Oracle: Equivalent sql statement to json_textcontains function

Tags: java, sql, arrays, json, oracle

I want to search for specific values in a json object, but can't use `json_textcontains`.

Table:

```
|   ID   |    NAME   |                    JSONCOLUMN               | ...
|   1    |    test   |{"key1" : "24", "key2": "35", "key3" : "57"} | ...
|   2    |    test2  |{"key1" : "67", "key2": "78", "key3" : "31"} | ...
|   3    |    test3  |{"key1" : "12", "key2": "35", "key3" : "99"} | ...
```

Now I have a search term e.g. "35" and want to get all rows that contain this term in the jsoncolumn as **value** (I don't want to search the keys).

So in the example above rows 1 and 3.

I can achieve that with folowing query:

```
select * from T t where JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(t.jsoncolumn, '$', '35')
```

But I cannot use `json_textcontains`. So I'm looking for an equivalent query.

Edit:
Clarified what I want to get from the query.

Comment: But... `json_textcontains` doesn't produce any output, it is just a condition. It doesn't extract any information from the JSON data.

Comment: Yeah, and the question is, is there another sql condition, which can search in json data. The above sql statement gives me the rows i want, but i can't use the json_textcontains in my query. So an equivalent replacement of the json_textcontains in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LIKE` condition or the `INSTR()` function for the matching.

However, just using this on `t.jsoncolumn` would find matches in the full json, i.e. also in the key part. To just search in the values, you could extract them first using `JSON_QUERY`.

Both

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t 
 WHERE JSON_QUERY(jsoncolumn, '$.*' WITH WRAPPER) LIKE '%35%'
```

and

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t
 WHERE INSTR(JSON_QUERY(t.jsoncolumn, '$.*' WITH WRAPPER), '35') > 0;
```

should produce the same result as your `JSON_TEXTCONTAINS()` example.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab446de8140437fb76d60f2f36cf7bd0).

Comment: I think we tried to use 'like' already, but this includes the keys and there is overlapping naming between keys and values, so i get rows where the key matches but not the value. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: No, you are right, this answer will also match in those cases, whereas `json_textcontains` will not. Before your edit, I did not get the question right.

Comment: Ok, yeah i tried to clarify it in the edit, sorry. Do you think what I'm looking for is possible?

Comment: You could use `JSON_QUERY`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, i got it to work with a few changes, i needed to use regexp_like, because i have many different conditions to match not just numbers like in my example. But your answer helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Sure, this will work with `regexp_like` as well. No need to say "thank you" on SO though, accepting and/or upvoting helpful answers (like you did) is the way to go.